# scraping a web site in python with requests-html library, it didn't get all the elements when selected by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to crawl https://edition.cnn.com/world with python by the snippet below. the problem is when using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the content, i didn't get all the data i wanted. i get 20 or so elements but there's alot more items that should have been selected

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://edition.cnn.com/world"
s = HTMLSession()
response = s.get(url)
response.html.render(wait=20)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.select('div.cd__wrapper')
print(len(results))  # returns 20 or so
```

basically i should use selenium but since there's not only this website, it could become bothersome. apparently the website uses some javascripts when loading so that is causing this problem.
I wonder what's the tweak here or is it possible to do this without being forced to use selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it would become rather annoying to find a new tweak for each new page instead of just using selenium to grab the html.

In principle, you could call up the individual requests that call up the respective `container-managers`

```
<script>CNN.covCon.push({id: "coverageContainer_8DDF4E26-8632-6418-1586-B910547ED120",layout: "list-hierarchical-xs",src: "/data/ocs/container/coverageContainer_8DDF4E26-8632-6418-1586-B910547ED120:list-hierarchical-xs/views/containers/common/container-manager.html"});</script>
```

again separately so that you don't have to work with `selenium` but then you would have to make such adjustments for every other page as well and that costs time and is not stable at all.

Just in case, it is not that much effort and you can process the html with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://edition.cnn.com/world')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser' )
len(soup.select('.cd__wrapper'))
```

Output --> 116

Comment: it worked great. can i ask whats the purpose of service?

Comment: With selenium4 as the key `executable_path` is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` - If you use selenium in a lower version, you won't need it.

Comment: ok. actually i've set path to my webdriver

Answer (score 0):

That's because whatever library or module you are using to pull your html tags might not be able to grab all the tags. Unfortunately wouldn't be able to tell unless i run your code.

1.) tags are in array so you must enumerate

OR

2.) beautifulsoup is having problems with the HTMLSession

Try using `from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq`

example of how to use:

```
xClient = uReq(YOUR_URL) 
Raw_html = xClient.read()
xClient.close()
```

ensure you close the connection after use.

Comment: This is showing same beahvior us in the question, isn't it? You also got only 21 elements in your resultset.

Comment: it seems nothing works but selenium