# Python webscrape CNN, some have results, some returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to web scrape and I tried doing multiple sites but the results aren't the same. This is the basic lines of code I always use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/world'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all(class_= 'cd__content')
print(data)
for i in data:
    print(i.getText())
```

If I replace the url with https://www.cnn.com/ , the result I receive is empty. They both have the same class 'cd__content'. Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: This could be due to JS rendering, which if I'm not mistaken BS4 does not support as Python is not client side...I'd double check that your element is there without JS before hoping there is a different simple solution

Comment: Do you suggest I should use Chrome or Firefox driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scraping a web site in python with requests-html library, it didn't get all the elements when selected by beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70555000/scraping-a-web-site-in-python-with-requests-html-library-it-didnt-get-all-the)

Comment: @nooonamee, are you thinking about using selenium now? With that I've had more ease setting up the chrome driver but either will work

Comment: @ViaTech I'm open to other options besides selenium. I took 2 Python courses on Udemy but none of them says anything about selenium or the problem I'm having right now :/